# Using Pull to Refresh gridview in viewpager in Activity inside ActivityGroup causes ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to use PullToRefresh GridView with ViewPager which is causing a crash giving ClassCastException. This is the Exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:360) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566) 
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581) 
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:845) 
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the code snippet where it is implemented.

```
PULL_TO_REFRESH = (PullToRefreshGridView)findViewById(R.id.groupList);
mGroupList = PULL_TO_REFRESH.getAdapterView();
Vector<View> pages = new Vector<View>();

        pages.add(mGroupList);

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this, pages);
        vp.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.

        PULL_TO_REFRESH.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
        });
```

This is the code snippet from PullToRefresh library which might be the cause.

```
package com.syncusup.pulltorefresh.library.my;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.syncusup.R;

public abstract class PullToRefreshBase<T extends AdapterView<ListAdapter>> extends LinearLayout implements
        OnTouchListener {

    private final class SmoothScrollRunnable implements Runnable {

        static final int ANIMATION_DURATION_MS = 190;
        static final int ANIMATION_FPS = 1000 / 60;

        private final Interpolator interpolator;
        private final int scrollToY;
        private final int scrollFromY;
        private final Handler handler;

        private boolean continueRunning = true;
        private long startTime = -1;
        private int currentY = -1;

        public SmoothScrollRunnable(Handler handler, int fromY, int toY) {
            this.handler = handler;
            this.scrollFromY = fromY;
            this.scrollToY = toY;
            this.interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            /**
             * Only set startTime if this is the first time we're starting, else
             * actually calculate the Y delta
             */
            if (startTime == -1) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else {

                /**
                 * We do do all calculations in long to reduce software float
                 * calculations. We use 1000 as it gives us good accuracy and
                 * small rounding errors
                 */
                long normalizedTime = (1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)) / ANIMATION_DURATION_MS;
                normalizedTime = Math.max(Math.min(normalizedTime, 1000), 0);

                final int deltaY = Math.round((scrollFromY - scrollToY)
                        * interpolator.getInterpolation(normalizedTime / 1000f));
                this.currentY = scrollFromY - deltaY;
                setHeaderScroll(currentY);
            }

            // If we're not at the target Y, keep going...
            if (continueRunning && scrollToY != currentY) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, ANIMATION_FPS);
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            this.continueRunning = false;
            this.handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }
    };

    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    static final int PULL_TO_REFRESH = 0;
    static final int RELEASE_TO_REFRESH = PULL_TO_REFRESH + 1;
    static final int REFRESHING = RELEASE_TO_REFRESH + 1;
    static final int EVENT_COUNT = 3;

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private int state = PULL_TO_REFRESH;
    private T adapterView;
    private boolean isPullToRefreshEnabled = true;

    private ProgressBar headerProgress;
    private TextView headerText;
    private ImageView headerImage;
    private Animation flipAnimation, reverseAnimation;
    private int headerHeight;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private OnTouchListener onTouchListener;
    private OnRefreshListener onRefreshListener;

    private SmoothScrollRunnable currentSmoothScrollRunnable;

    private float startY = -1;
    private final float[] lastYs = new float[EVENT_COUNT];

    private String releaseLabel;
    private String pullLabel;
    private String refreshingLabel;

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    public PullToRefreshBase(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PullToRefreshBase(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    /**
     * Get the Wrapped AdapterView. Anything returned here has already been
     * added to the content view.
     * 
     * @return The AdapterView which is currently wrapped
     */
    public final T getAdapterView() {
        return adapterView;
    }

    /**
     * Whether Pull-to-Refresh is enabled
     * 
     * @return enabled
     */
    public boolean isPullToRefreshEnabled() {
        return isPullToRefreshEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Mark the current Refresh as complete. Will Reset the UI and hide the
     * Refreshing View
     */
    public void onRefreshComplete() {
        resetHeader();
    }

    public void setOnRefreshListener(OnRefreshListener listener) {
        onRefreshListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * A mutator to enable/disable Pull-to-Refresh for the current AdapterView
     * 
     * @param enable
     *            Whether Pull-To-Refresh should be used
     */
    public void setPullToRefreshEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.isPullToRefreshEnabled = enabled;
    }

    public void setReleaseLabel(String releaseLabel) {
        this.releaseLabel = releaseLabel;
    }

    public void setPullLabel(String pullLabel) {
        this.pullLabel = pullLabel;
    }

    public void setRefreshingLabel(String refreshingLabel) {
        this.refreshingLabel = refreshingLabel;
    }

    public void setHeaderProgress(ProgressBar headerProgress) {
        this.headerProgress = headerProgress;
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
        onTouchListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev) {
        if (isPullToRefreshEnabled) {
            // Returning true here stops the ListView being scrollable while we
            // refresh
            if (state == REFRESHING) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return onAdapterViewTouch(view, ev);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This is implemented by derived classes to return the created AdapterView.
     * If you need to use a custom AdapterView (such as a custom ListView),
     * override this method and return an instance of your custom class.
     * 
     * Be sure to set the ID of the view in this method, especially if you're
     * using a ListActivity or ListFragment.
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     *            AttributeSet from wrapped class. Means that anything you
     *            include in the XML layout declaration will be routed to the
     *            AdapterView
     * @return New instance of the AdapterView
     */
    protected abstract T createAdapterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs);

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    protected final void resetHeader() {
        state = PULL_TO_REFRESH;
        initializeYsHistory();
        startY = -1;
        headerImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headerProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        smoothScrollTo(0);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Header
        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.pull_to_refresh_header, this,
                false);
        headerText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_text);
        pullLabel = context.getString(R.string.pull_to_refresh_pull_label);
        refreshingLabel = context.getString(R.string.pull_to_refresh_refreshing_label);
        releaseLabel = context.getString(R.string.pull_to_refresh_release_label);
        headerImage = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_image);
        headerProgress = (ProgressBar) header.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_progress);
        addView(header, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        measureView(header);
        headerHeight = header.getMeasuredHeight();

        // AdapterView
        // By passing the attrs, we can add ListView/GridView params via XML
        adapterView = this.createAdapterView(context, attrs);
        adapterView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        addView(adapterView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        // Animations
        flipAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, -180, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        flipAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        flipAnimation.setDuration(250);
        flipAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        reverseAnimation = new RotateAnimation(-180, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f);
        reverseAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        reverseAnimation.setDuration(250);
        reverseAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        // Hide Header View
        setPadding(getPaddingLeft(), -headerHeight, getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom());
    }

    private void measureView(View child) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = child.getLayoutParams();
        if (p == null) {
            p = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }

        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(0, 0 + 0, p.width);
        int lpHeight = p.height;
        int childHeightSpec;
        if (lpHeight > 0) {
            childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lpHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        } else {
            childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        }
        child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
    }

    private boolean onAdapterViewTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                updateEventStates(event);

                if (isPullingDownToRefresh() && startY == -1) {
                    if (startY == -1) {
                        startY = event.getY();
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                if (startY != -1 && !adapterView.isPressed()) {
                    pullDown(event, startY);
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                initializeYsHistory();
                startY = -1;

                if (state == RELEASE_TO_REFRESH) {
                    setRefreshing();
                    if (onRefreshListener != null) {
                        onRefreshListener.onRefresh();
                    }
                } else {
                    smoothScrollTo(0);
                }
                break;
        }

        if (null != onTouchListener) {
            return onTouchListener.onTouch(view, event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void pullDown(MotionEvent event, float firstY) {
        float averageY = average(lastYs);

        int height = (int) (Math.max(averageY - firstY, 0));
        setHeaderScroll(height);

        if (state == PULL_TO_REFRESH && headerHeight < height) {
            state = RELEASE_TO_REFRESH;
            headerText.setText(releaseLabel);
            headerImage.clearAnimation();
            headerImage.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
        }
        if (state == RELEASE_TO_REFRESH && headerHeight >= height) {
            state = PULL_TO_REFRESH;
            headerText.setText(pullLabel);
            headerImage.clearAnimation();
            headerImage.startAnimation(reverseAnimation);
        }
    }

    private void setHeaderScroll(int y) {
        scrollTo(0, -y);
    }

    private int getHeaderScroll() {
        return -getScrollY();
    }

    private void setRefreshing() {
        state = REFRESHING;
        headerText.setText(refreshingLabel);
        headerImage.clearAnimation();
        headerImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        headerProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        smoothScrollTo(headerHeight);
    }

    private float average(float[] ysArray) {
        float avg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < EVENT_COUNT; i++) {
            avg += ysArray[i];
        }
        return avg / EVENT_COUNT;
    }

    private void initializeYsHistory() {
        for (int i = 0; i < EVENT_COUNT; i++) {
            lastYs[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    private void updateEventStates(MotionEvent event) {
        for (int i = 0; i < EVENT_COUNT - 1; i++) {
            lastYs[i] = lastYs[i + 1];
        }

        float y = event.getY();
        int top = adapterView.getTop();
        lastYs[EVENT_COUNT - 1] = y + top;
    }

    private boolean isPullingDownToRefresh() {
        return isPullToRefreshEnabled && state != REFRESHING && isUserDraggingDownwards() && isFirstVisible();
    }

    private boolean isFirstVisible() {
        if (this.adapterView.getCount() == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (adapterView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
            return adapterView.getChildAt(0).getTop() >= adapterView.getTop();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isUserDraggingDownwards() {
        return this.isUserDraggingDownwards(0, EVENT_COUNT - 1);
    }

    private boolean isUserDraggingDownwards(int from, int to) {
        return lastYs[from] != 0 && lastYs[to] != 0 && Math.abs(lastYs[from] - lastYs[to]) > 10
                && lastYs[from] < lastYs[to];
    }

    private void smoothScrollTo(int y) {
        if (null != currentSmoothScrollRunnable) {
            currentSmoothScrollRunnable.stop();
        }

        this.currentSmoothScrollRunnable = new SmoothScrollRunnable(handler, getHeaderScroll(), y);
        handler.post(currentSmoothScrollRunnable);
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================

    public static interface OnRefreshListener {

        public void onRefresh();

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing, 
I would add that it happens on API level that actually needs the Support package (API 11+). Or later version it's OK.

Comment: You can check if the library is using the same file of the support library or not.

Answer (score 1):

For a better answer, I'd have to see your implementation of `CustomPagerAdapter`.

But since the constructor of `CustomPagerAdapter` takes an array/collection/vector of `Views` as a parameter, would it be correct to assume that the `CustomPagerAdapter`'s `instantiateItem` method (or `getItem` method if your `CustomPagerAdapter` is a `FragmentPagerAdapter`) use theses `Views` to build the `ViewPager`'s pages?

If so, that may be your problem.

The `Vector<View> pages` variable contains `Views` that are *already* part of a layout. In this case, the (only) `View` in there is the `mGroupList`. The `mGroupList` is `already` part of a layout. You can't make a `View` (`mGroupList` in this case) be the child of two different parents.

Instead of 'finding' the `mGroupList`, create a brand new `PullToRefreshGridView` in the `instantiateItem` method of your `CustomPagerAdapter` (either through code or by inflating the appropriate layout-xml). The brand new `PullToRefreshGridView` instance won't have a parent right there and then, but will become a child of the ViewPager when the ViewPager deems it necessary.

To make things more simple, I suggest using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead, which will return a proper `Fragment` in its `getItem` method. The `Fragment` will then return the correct view in its `onCreateView` method, containing the `PullToRefreshGridView` you want.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html